# Deadlock in multithread and bulk inserting into a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, multithreading, qt, deadlock

I have a program (in this case in QT) which tries to insert 4000 records simultaneously into `source_names` table by 8 threads: 500 records by each thread.

My table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `source_names` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `source_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx` (`source_name`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=101952 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

As specified in the above code, my `source_name` column is `UNIQUE`  .

So I have 8 threads that each of them executes this codes at the same time:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO source_names (source_name) VALUES ('a001'),('a002'),...,('a500')
```

and if there is a duplicate `source_name`, there is a warning and nothing will be happen.

But the main problem is that sometimes there is `Deadlock` error and I can not handle it:

```
Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction QMYSQL3: Unable to execute statement
```

I think this is because of `UNIQUE` column. If I use just one thread there is no problem, but how can I solve that with multiple threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MySQL Reference Manual
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/concurrent-inserts.html

> If there are multiple INSERT statements, they are queued and performed in sequence, concurrently with the SELECT statements.

Since MySQL does not insert records simultaneously, you can use a single thread and avoid deadlocks.

If you must have multi threads that INSERT, consider using try-catch blocks.
If deadlock occurs, try to insert again.
If you end up in an infinite loop, put a counter and don't try to insert forever. Instead try to insert only a predefined time(counter) by you.